# WebPart Serializable

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013

I have the following question:

I'm working on a project that contains a ReportViewer control. I need to safe this control in Session using the following sentence:

```
[Serializable]
[ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public partial class VisualReportViewer : WebPart
{
     ......

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         .....
         ViewState["ReportViewer1"] = ReportViewer1;
         .....
     }

     .....
}
```

This sentence display the following error message:

```
Type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer' in Assembly Microsoft.ReportingServices.SharePoint.UI.WebParts, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' is not marked as serializable.
```

As you can see, I added Serializable in the top of the class without solution. Are there some way to do it? Is it possible to save the webparts controls to use in the current Session?

Comment: Why do you use `ViewState` instead of `Session`?

Comment: Now I use Session, but the problem persist...

Comment: Do you use the default session without configuring it to use sql? If so - your objects do not need to be Serializable, because the default session is stored in memory.